# How do you pass the result from one function into another function?

Tags: c, function

Please consider this code example:

```
int func1(int,int); // function 1 prototype
int func2(int); // function 2 prototype
```

I am trying to send the output of function-1 as the input to function-2, but have been unsuccessful till now.

If someone could please explain the same with an example, that would be great.
Also, is the same possible with respect to Pass-by value and Pass-by-reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? Do you mean the value _returned_ by `func1`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: ya mte thats what i meant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply

```
int x = func2(func1(1,2));
```

Comment: this implies you can not pass by reference as the return value of func1 is in the EAX register.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = func2(func1(7, 9));
```

Just pass the expression containing the call to `func1` as the argument to `func2`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by nesting functions:

```
func2( func1(42, 24) );
```

Nesting lots of functions can easily become hard to read, so for more readability you could store the return value of func1 in a temporary variable:

```
int tmp = func1(42, 24);
func2(tmp);
```

Regarding your question about pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value: In all these function calls, the parameters are passed by value. That's because the function signatures define the parameters as `int`, not `int *`

Comment: Passing a parameter of type `int *` is still pass-by-value. The parameter is a pointer, you're passing the value of it, and making changes to the pointer in the function (the _pointer_, not the value being pointed at) has no effect on the caller.

Comment: if it's really C, then everything is passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers said: `func2( func1(1, 2) );`

In C you can only pass parameters by value. Now having said that, passing the value of a pointer that points to the memory you want to change achieves the same effect as passing by reference.

```
int foo(int *x){
   printf("The address that you passed to the function is: %x", x);
   printf("The value is: %d", *x);
   *x = 10;
}
int mem;
foo(&mem); //print the address of mem
```

in C++, you can pass by refference.

```
int foo(int &x){
   printf("The address that you passed to the function is: %x", &x);
   printf("The value is: %d", x);
   x = 10;
}
int mem;
foo(mem); //print the address of mem
```